# Install driver for RT5370 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers, wireless-adapter

I try to install a driver for my wireless adapter Ralink RT5370. I downloaded on the website http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01_windows.php?sn=501 the driver for Linux.

Then I have modified:

- In `os/linux/config.mk` `'HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y', 'HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y' and 'WFLAGS += -DCONFIG_STA_SUPPORT' (removed "-DDBG" from the line)`
- In Makefile

  ```
  ifeq ($(CHIPSET),)  
  CHIPSET = 5370  
  endif     (instead of 5572 5370 etc.)
  ```

Then I have done:

```
$sudo make && sudo make install
$sudo modprobe rt5572sta
```

+reboot but does not work. rt5572sta was the only module that was proposed for `modprobe`.

I am on 12.04

```
$lsusb
...
... Ralink Technology Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
...

$lsmod
...
rt5572sta 739308 0 
...

$uname -r -m 
3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686
```

Does anyone know how to make it work please? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe more of a question for http://www.askubuntu.com

Comment: Ubuntu should already have drivers for the RT5370s, shouldn't need to use the vendor drivers.

Comment: Could you pls post he output of lspci -vnn | grep -i net? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are trying to use the wrong driver. Issue the following command:

```
  modinfo rt2800usb | grep 5370
```

and see whether the output is:

```
  alias:          usb:v148Fp5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

or something very similar, containing the the string

```
  v148Fp5370
```

If this is so, then you are using the wrong driver. Try instead

```
  sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
  sudo rmmod rt5572sta
  sudo modprobe rt2800usb
```

and see whether this works now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in debian stretch today (new install) I see my wifi router but it wont connect. It has the rt2800usb module modprobed.

```
[10706.100166] wlx7cdd9049493a: authenticated
[10722.074791] wlx7cdd9049493a: authenticate with 50:a7:2b:58:8a:29
[10722.101567] wlx7cdd9049493a: send auth to 50:a7:2b:58:8a:29 (try 1/3)
[10722.103009] wlx7cdd9049493a: authenticated
[10730.714846] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx7cdd9049493a: link is not ready
[10730.906698] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx7cdd9049493a: link is not ready
```